# How to check whether the list have items in Ansible Rundeck

Tags: ansible, rundeck

**Objective:**

- Find out files in a directory with a pattern and put them in a list
- And then check whether the list is empty. If its not empty, then extract the file name.

**Code:**

```
- name: "Find the text files"
    find:
      paths: /directory/
      patterns: '*.txt'
    register: file_in_directory

  - name: Get the file name and its path
    set_fact:
      file_name_with_path: "{{ file_in_directory.files[0].path }}"
    when: "{{ file_in_directory.files[0].path }}" != ""
```

**Problem:**
The when condition is failing.

```
when: "{{ file_in_directory.files[0].path }}" != ""
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Use json_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
when: file_in_directory.matched > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try:

```
when: file_in_directory.files | length > 0
```